# Consequence of overstaying US visa

Tags: usa, overstaying, nigerian-citizens

I have a US visa valid for 2 years. I thought I could stay that long but, on my arrival at the port of entry, I was told I could only stay in the US until the 1st of June 2017.

Today is 8th of July and I'm still in the US. I want to leave next month and go back to my country, Nigeria, but I am scared of what might happen if I want to return to the US next year.

What will happen if I come back next year? What will happen to my current visa?

Answer (score 11):

> if you overstay the end date of your authorized stay, as provided by the CBP officer at a port-of-entry, or United States Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS), your visa will automatically void or cancel

https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html

You must apply for a new visa if you want to visit again. You will overstay less than 180 days so you will not be banned. However, unless you have strong proof to convince the visa officer that you will not breach your visa again, you will not get the visa.

If you get caught before you leave, it's going to be another story.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. So even if i stay less than 180 days, my visa is still going to be canceled?

Comment: Your visa is void now

Comment: @Sam Your visa will be void even if you stay one day beyond your authorized stay.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would the US know they had overstayed?  Would it help to walk across a land border like Stanstead or Tijuana and present themselves to CA/MX immigration?  Or would this be reported back to the US...

Comment: To be specific, it's INA 222(g) that causes the visa to automatically become void when you stay past the date on the I-94. In addition to making the visa void, it also restricts him to apply for US visas only in his country of nationality for the rest of his life.

Comment: @Harper The US exit tracking system has some holes, but if they think you've overstayed (and you can [check your records online](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/)), the burden is on you to demonstrate that you haven't. In this case though, the OP has overstayed.